# How does Incendiary cloud affect Iron Golems?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters

Incediary Cloud bypasses Spell Resistance, so golems' Spell Immunity should have no effect on it.
However Iron Golems' spell immunity has additional rule, that magical fire damae heals them - so does it affect the Incendiary Cloud too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The effectively unbeatable spell resistance and the healing from magical fire are not dependent on each other.  All magical fire damage, regardless of source, will be similarly affected.

Note that not all magically-created fire will necessarily count as dealing magical fire damage; Some may argue that instantaneous [Creation](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#creation) spells are exempt because "the created object or creature is merely assembled through magic. It lasts indefinitely and does not depend on magic for its existence".  Similarly, a torch ignited by magical means may be considered to be nonetheless dealing 1 point of nonmagical fire damage as opposed to the magical sort.  in any case *Incendiary Cloud* has a duration of 1 round/level and so certainly deals magical fire damage.

Comment: Worth noting that *instantaneous* SR: No Conjuration (Creation) spells would be creating *nonmagical* fire that would not heal iron golems.